# Using _.where with multiple criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I want to collect the records where ftprnt = A or B but not C.  This code sample works fine to collect the records where ftprnt = A but I can't figure out how to add the second criterion.

```
var x = _.where(v, {'ftprnt': ['A']});
```

I've tried variations of or / || but can't seem to get it to work.  Need some help

Alternatively, I would except a solution where I could just filter out the records where ftprnt = C

Comment: Yes, use `find` or `filter` with a proper predicate function instead of `where`.

Comment: `var x = v.filter(item => item.ftprnt === 'A' || item.ftprnt === 'B')` or `var x = v.filter(item => item.ftprnt !== 'C')`

Comment: Thanks.  Got it working with Filter.  item.ftprnt is an array, ended up with v.filter(item => item.ftprnt[0] !== 'C')

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Probably you have solved it but for other people, they can try this:

```
var x = _.where(v, {ftprnt:'A', ftprnt:'B'});
```